# Show Wii U Gamepad Video on Computer

Tags: controllers, wii-u

I'm trying to find out if anyone has come up with a method of getting the Wii U gamepad video to show on a PC.
I've looked this up and found people playing PC games with the Wii U, but that's not what I am trying to do.

I want to duplicate what is on the Wii U Gamepad onto my computer. I would think this could be possible since it's already wireless.

Comment: I think it'd be easier to mirror the video feed from the Wii U to the PC, instead of redirecting it through the gamepad. One less stop means less lag. But there's just one little problem: the Wii U uses a highly specialised wireless signal that's been optimised for video streaming and is possibly using a spectrum not covered by standard 2.4 or 5 GHz devices to avoid interference and bandwidth contention.

Comment: Definitely true. If I had an HDMI capture card I would definitely do that. Just thought this would be interesting to test out if someone had managed to make it work already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using drc-sim-client by rolandoislas you can.

Not only with PC but also with Android. Available in the google play store.

First you need a linux computer to host as the server. OSX and Windows host m

> Minimum Linux based OS
>   2.4 GHz CPU 5GHZ, 802.11n compatible wireless networking interface
>
> DRC Sim Server is a utility for pairing a computer to a Wii U to
>   emulate a gamepad.
>
> It needs a [client](https://github.com/rolandoislas/drc-sim-client/wiki/Home) for full functionality.
>   See the [wiki](https://github.com/rolandoislas/drc-sim/wiki/Home) for more info.

## Installation

Installation instructions are available on the [wiki](https://github.com/rolandoislas/drc-sim/wiki/Home).

You will install some things and run some scripts by copying and pasting what you see on the wiki.

NOTE: Issues may be encountered with Ubuntu versions greater than 16.04 LTS.
There's some conflicting info on what the recommended machine is but it says

> The install script supports only Debian based OSes at this time.

You can find his open source program here which links to the client and wiki.

https://github.com/rolandoislas/drc-sim

Answer (score -1):

There is a team that has discovered the way to do this, but you will still need a TV for the first screen and a Bluetooth dongle. [This is the video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt2-IRiWd40)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any sense.  All it does is redirect the user to a Youtube video.